# Getting indices of a specific value in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the foll. numpy array:

```
arr = [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
```

This is how I am getting the indices of all 0's in the array:

```
inds = []
for index,item in enumerate(arr):     
    if item == 0:
        inds.append(index)
```

Is there a numpy function to do the same?

Comment: arr = np.array([0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1])   convert to array for clarity and then ...
>>> np.where(arr==0)
(array([ 0,  1,  2,  4,  5, ..., 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]),)  is one method. slice the where with [0] just to get the indices

Comment: is [`numpy.argwhere`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) what you're after? Something like `numpy.argwhere(arr == 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> arr = np.array([0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1])
>>> (arr==0).nonzero()[0]
array([ 0,  1,  2,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 12, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
       21, 22, 23, 24, 25])
```

Comment: thanks @John, what does the [0] at the end of nonzero do?

Comment: @user308827, `nonzero` returns a tuple of arrays, one for each dimension of `arr`. You only have one dimension, but you still need `[0]` there to pull it out of the tuple

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`numpy.argwhere`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) as @chappers pointed out in the comment:

```
arr = np.array([0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1])

In [34]: np.argwhere(arr == 0).flatten()
Out[34]:
array([ 0,  1,  2,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 12, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
       21, 22, 23, 24, 25], dtype=int32)
```

Or with inverse of `astype(bool)`:

```
In [63]: (~arr.astype(bool)).nonzero()[0]
Out[63]:
array([ 0,  1,  2,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 12, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
       21, 22, 23, 24, 25], dtype=int32)
```